# Making the languages not bold in moderncv

Tags: formatting, bold, moderncv

I'm writing my CV with the moderncv package and I'd like the un-bold the text in front of each language.

In the following example, "Spoken" and "Barely Spoken" are bold, which I don't like.
I searched in the moderncv.cls file but I can't find "\cvlanguage" definition, although I can find \cventry

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{The burger flipper}
\address{The big street}{neverland}
\mobile{MyMobile000000}
\email{mymail@mymail.com}
\extrainfo{99 year-old}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Languages}
\cvlanguage{language1}{Spoken}{bla bla dygfzeiu rzegouerhg regoeru}
\cvlanguage{language2}{Barely Spoken}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The definition of `\cvlanguage` is in `moderncvcompatibility.sty` and it is `\newcommand*{\cvlanguage}[3]{\cvitemwithcomment{#1}{#2}{#3}}`. So you had to find the re-definition of `\cvitemwithcomment` in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
```

so that your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{The burger flipper}
\address{The big street}{neverland}
\mobile{MyMobile000000}
\email{mymail@mymail.com}
\extrainfo{99 year-old}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Languages}
\cvlanguage{language1}{Spoken}{bla bla dygfzeiu rzegouerhg regoeru}
\cvlanguage{language2}{Barely Spoken}{}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that (thanks to Werner for the comment) you can also replace the above three lines with

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\xpatchcmd*{\cvitemwithcomment}{\bfseries}{\mdseries}{}{}
```

In this case, the `*`-variant of `\xpatchcmd` is used to replace both instances of `\bfseries`.

---

Instead, if you need to change it only for one instance, you can insert `\mdseries` (which overwrites the default `\bfseries`) in the second argument, for example

```
\cvlanguage{language1}{\mdseries Spoken}{bla bla dygfzeiu rzegouerhg regoeru}
```

Comment: [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) allows for `\xpatchcmd*`, which does a "replace-all". See [my deleted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142443/5764) (take it if you feel it necessary).

Comment: @Werner, thanks. I'll add it in the answer (never used that package before).

Comment: @karlkoeller One should be careful in replacing `xpatch` with `regexpatch`: if the command to be patched contains “`@`-commands” the patch should be between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in any case (with `xpatch` it would be necessary only if the actual arguments to `\xpatchcmd` contains `@`-commands). I'm thinking how to lift off this limitation. It's not really serious: before trying to patch a command one has to see its definition anyway.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your comment. I've never used `regexpatch` before, so I'll take a look at its documentation. In this case, the re-definition of `\cvitemwithcomment` does not contain any "`@`-commands". Should I add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` anyway?

Comment: @karlkoeller Only if the original macro body contains `@`-commands.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redefining any definition you can redefine `\bfseries`. Of course the results in the drawback that you can't use `\bfseries` inside you current `\cvlanguage`.

```
\begingroup
\let\bfseries\relax
\cvlanguage{language1}{Spoken}{bla bla dygfzeiu rzegouerhg regoeru}
\endgroup
```

Comment: A minor work-around is required if you actually want to use `\bfseries` anywhere within that construct though...